# Select by location only selecting a few of the features within boundary using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, select-by-location

[image]

So I select my municipal boundary and I want to select all the zoning districts inside it.

[image]

This is how I filled out my select by location query

[image]

Now it only selects a few of the zoning districts within my municipal boundary! I want it to select all of them within.   Any reason why?

Comment: The [help file](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/select-layer-by-location.htm#GUID-CC074F49-345A-4FEE-A1B4-D4FC92ED0E9C) says WITHIN means if they are COMPLETLY within, touching edges are not completely within...

Comment: Use a small buffer of your selecting polygon if you want to use *within*, in these cases I use *intersect* with a small negative buffer... that usually gets the result I'm after.

Comment: @hornbydd thanks!  i guess i thought that was difference between within and completely within haha.

Comment: @MichaelStimson - I like the negative buffer suggestion with intersect, never knew you could do that.  Thanks for sharing!